# Why using custom repeatable annotation as AOP pointcut in Springboot doesn't work?

Tags: java, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop, spring-annotations

I used the custom annotation `@SendMessage` as the pointcut for my aspect, and since a method may send multiple messages, I set the `@SendMessage` annotation to `Repeatable`, defined `@AfterReturning` in my aspect class, and set this annotation twice on the methods, which have different messages.

I then noticed in my testing that the logic in the pointcut would not execute, even though the gutter icon was displayed in IDEA and I could jump between the method and the aspect.

I tried just using one `@SendMessage` annotation on the method and I was pleasantly surprised to find that it worked and it would execute the logic in the pointcut.

Why does Repeatable invalidate the aop? Or what causes aop to fail?

First I defined a custom annotation @SendMessage, then to make it support `Repeatable` I defined its container annotation @SendMessages:

```java
// SendMessage.java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Repeatable(value = SendMessages.class)
public @interface SendMessage {
    String message();
}
```

```java
// SendMessages.java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface SendMessages {
    SendMessage[] value();
}
```

After that I defined the aspect class `SendMessageAspect`:

```java
// SendMessageAspect.java
@Aspect
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
@Slf4j
public class SendMessageAspect {
    private final SendMessageService service;

    @Pointcut(value = "within(com.example.service..*) && (@annotation(sendMessage))")
    private void sendMessagePointcut(SendMessage sendMessage) {
    }

    @AfterReturning(value = "sendMessagePointcut(sendMessage)", returning = "returnValue", argNames = "jp,sendMessage,returnValue")
    public void sendMessage(JoinPoint jp, SendMessage sendMessage, Object returnValue) {
        // The code like this
        service.sendMessage();
    }
}
```

Finally I add the `@SendMessage` annotation to the method that need to use the Aspect:

```java
// OrderServiceImpl.java
@Slf4j
@Service
public class OrderServiceImpl implements OrderService {
    @SendMessage(message = "message1")
    @SendMessage(message = "message2")
    public Order orderSomething(String productId) {
        // some code internal
        return order;
    }
}
```

I find that the `orderSomeing` method returns normally but doesn't execute the `sendMessage` method in Aspect, no error occured, in IDEA it is possible to navigate between the two classes with the gutter icon.

I tried again using only one annotation on the method, and this time it worked, executing the logic in Aspect when the method returns successfully:

```java
// OrderServiceImpl.java
@Slf4j
@Service
public class OrderServiceImpl implements OrderService {
    @SendMessage(message = "message")
    public Order orderSomething(String productId) {
        // some code internal
        return order;
    }
}
```

so, this is why and how to solve it? I think it's the `Repeatable` issue.